# Java Error: Bad Operand Type for binary operator <

Tags: java, arrays, generics, operator-keyword, operand

```
public class MaxMinArray<T>{

  private T getMin(T[] arr){

    T min = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
      min = (arr[i] < min) ? arr[i] : min;
    }
    return min;
  }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  MaxMinArray<Integer> m = new MaxMinArray<Integer>();
  Integer[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
  System.out.println(m.getMin(arr));

  }

}
```

I am getting the following error. I dont understand why can I not use <, if T is a type variable and not an object ?

```
  error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
      if (arr[i] < min){
                 ^
  first type:  T
  second type: T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class MaxMinArray
```

Also, since I am using T for generics, is it a good idea to define my array as Integer and not int. If not, how should I define an array of integers?

Thank you!

Comment: A type variable denotes a reference type, so it's as if `T` is an object type. (The compiler error also implies this when it says *"where `T` is a type-variable: `T extends Object`"*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr[i]` contains some `Object` of some generic type `T`. You cannot use the `<` operator on an `Object`.

Do this instead:

```
public class MaxMinArray<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private T getMin(T[] arr){
         T min = arr[0];
         for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
             min = (arr[i].compareTo(min) < 0) ? arr[i] : min;
         }
         return min;
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: Yep, I forgot that generic types use `extends` for interfaces rather than `implements`, usually my IDE reminds me. @Logan thanks for the edit.

Comment: No problem. I would also add the type parameter to `Comparable` -- `T extends Comparable<T>`

Comment: @Logan thank you! You solved my next doubt already. I was getting a raw type warning because there was no type parameter to Comparable.

Comment: @noogler no problem! Yeah, if you just specify `Comparable`, it is essentially `Comparable<Object>`.

Comment: @noogler sorry that my answer was slightly borked, it was a bit rushed and no IDE to catch the slip-ups.

Comment: Its okayy !! It still helped me :D @xtratic